# Heartrate measuring using capacitive touch sensor

Tags: sensor, atmel, capacitive, biopotential

I am new here, and I hope someone could help me.
So I've read in the datasheet of the capacitive touch sensor ATMEL42QT1011
that we could use it as a heart rate sensor.But what I don't understand is will we need an electrode. How do we wire SNS and SNSK and the output of the chip will be in the analog input of the microcontroller ? 
thank you very much

Comment: link to the data sheet please

Comment: [link](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-9542-AT42-QTouch-BSW-AT42QT1011_Datasheet.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood the data sheet.

The 'heartbeat' function (page 10 para 3.9.2) reports on the integrity of the IC.

It **may** be possible to use the IC to detect the position change of (let's say) the skin above the radial artery with the pulse, by changing the distance slowly until the motion was detected, but it won't be easy, or stable. If it had a facility to alter the sensitivity by programming, then movement would not be necessary. Unfortunately, the data sheet only talks about sensitivity in terms of electrode sizes, capacitor values, distances, no mention of software control.

Try a red LED and analogue photo-detector pair. Shone at the fingertip, the reflection is modulated by the pulsing of blood in the finger. With an analogue output, it's possible to auto-bias to get a clean pulse (I've done it).

Comment: But a LED and anlogue photo-detector pair can only be used in fingertrip and i need to detect the heartbeat on a radial artery or on chest

Comment: ... if you say so! However, it might be worth trying something that works on a finger on the chest or the radial artery, just in case you're wrong. What's certain is that the 42QT1011 is not going to work for you.

Comment: I don't know i am not certain , but I know someone who told me that it works well, I think I am going to try both and take the better option.